# Bootstrap - JUST the Validation Styles are Missing

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I've got bootstrap CSS (`bootstrap.min.css`, to be specific) referenced and working fine - I have `form-group`, `btn btn-important` and a host of other Bootstrap CSS classes displaying just fine - but my validation classes (like `field-validation-error`) seem to not have a corresponding CSS declaration... that I can find, anyway.

Where are they; what am I missing?  Is there some other CSS file that I don't have?

Comment: do you have bootstrap.js referenced?

Comment: I do, yes - `.Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.js")` - but surely the CSS declarations aren't in the .js file?

Comment: Where are you the CSS reference `field-validation-error` from? Does seem like it is a built-in utility class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if I look at bootstrap documentation here (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#custom-styles), I get know there is no css class defination for `field-validation-error`. For validation, you need to add `form-control` class in the `<input />` element and it applies style as per the `:invalid` or `:valid` css4 pseudo selectors.

There also is an option to use css3 way here(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/forms/#server-side). Just need to add `is-invalid` or `is-valid` class at the `<input />` element along with the `form-control` class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input class="form-control is-invalid" />
<br/>
<input class="form-control is-valid" />
```